# Expand PV from Kubernetes no-provision storageclass

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to deploy the Confluent for Kafka (zookeeper statefulset) and part of the documentation mentions that I should be able to resize it, meaning that my storageclass should have `allowVolumeExpansion: true` set.

While the [listed supported on-prem storage solutions](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-storage.html) are only Ceph RBD and Portworx, if not using Dynamic Provisioning, the given example is of provisioner `no-provisioner`.

I would like to know if using a storageclass provisioner with `no-provisioner` does not actually allow me to resize the persistent storage volumes.

For reference:

My SC manifest is as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: my-storage-class
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

I am able to create it.
As for the PV manifest, it is as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: my-storage-class
  local:
     path: /mnt/app/data1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
```

Then, I follow the steps below:

- Add a new disk to my VM
- Expand LVM vg with new disk
- Expand LVM lv with free space
- Change PV/PVC storage capacity and request
- Rollout restart the sts

Once I exec into the Pod and check the FS size, it still shows 10Gb.

Comment: What command do you use to check the file system size?

Comment: @gohm'c, i'm using df -h

Answer (score 0):

The issue was Linux side, I forgot to run resize2fs.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you cannot set `allowVolumeExpansion: true` when using `no-provisioner` type of StorageClass (you can but it won't work). Supported types are listed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#allow-volume-expansion).

Expanding Persistent Volume Claims is also not supported in this type of storage.

The workaround you can try is to:

1. Resize current StatefulSet to 0 replicas.
2. Delete existing PV/PVC.
3. Update the desired capacity in manifest of PV/PVC.
4. Apply PV/PVC
5. Resize StatefulSet to desired amount of Pods.